# Automatically renaming downloaded files on Mac

Tags: macos, file, rename, automator, renaming

I've been trying to find a way to **automatically rename my downloaded files** on my Macbook Pro, but I somehow can't. I've tried using Automator and having a folder action that renames the files coming into the folder, but somehow it doesn't work at all, as if it was disabled.

Does anybody have any idea on how I could **rename them automatically when they're downloaded**, so that it's easier to keep them in order (mainly for myself), for archiving reasons.

The way I want to rename them is simply to add the creation date to it, just like this script should work.

[Folder Script Automator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0pmI.png)

However, this does rename them, but it never stops, it keeps adding the date in eternity, and of course I'd only like it once in the beginning.

[What it really does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7jZI.png)

Comment: Automatically rename them **from** what **to** what?

Comment: Show your _Automator_ workflow.  And then describe exactly how you want them to be renamed.  I can easily write you a script to rename them all to `"file.txt"`.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: If you rename them into the same folder, they trigger another rename, and another rename....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this following AppleScript code in Script Editor.app as “Move And Rename.scpt” to your folder…    /Users/YOUR SHORT NAME/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions/

To be able to rename the files using a folder action, the files to be renamed must be moved to a different folder otherwise it will create an infinite loop

The only thing you need to do is create a folder in your downloads folder and name it … Renamed Files.  This is where the renamed files will be placed

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    tell application "Finder" to set theNewItems to files of folder theFolder

    repeat with i from 1 to count of theNewItems
        set theFile to item i of theNewItems
        set moveToFolder to (path to downloads folder as text) & "Renamed Files:"

        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
        set theLongDate to (current date)
        set theLongDate to (date string of theLongDate)
        set currentMonth to (word 1 of text item 2 of theLongDate)
        set currentDay to (word 2 of text item 2 of theLongDate)
        set currentYear to (word 1 of text item 3 of theLongDate)
        set monthList to {January, February, March, April, May, June, ¬
            July, August, September, October, November, December}
        repeat with x from 1 to 12
            if currentMonth = ((item x of monthList) as string) then
                set theRequestNumber to (text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & x))
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        set currentMonth to theRequestNumber
        set currentDay to (text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & currentDay))
        set theShortDate to (currentYear & "-" & currentMonth & "-" & currentDay) as string

        set newName to theShortDate

        tell application "Finder"
            set theName to name of theFile
            move theFile to moveToFolder
            set theFile to moveToFolder & theName
            try
                set name of alias theFile to newName & " " & theName
            on error errMsg number errNum
                set name of alias theFile to newName & " 1 " & theName
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Once you have saved that file to that location, it will then be ready to attach to any folder you choose in Finder.app as a folder action

[image]

[image]

Comment: I realized as I saw this that there's an easier way, just add a "Move Finder Items" to my old Automator script. Still don't get it why it has to go into an infinite loop.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The infinite loop happens because the folder action is monitoring that folder for newly added files. Renaming a file in that folder triggers the folder action again because it sees the new named file as a new file being added to the folder